# Which stream is used with Bitmap.Compress()?

Tags: c#, file, xamarin, bitmap, stream

I try to compress a bitmap into Jpeg, yet it seems like the only stream I can pass to `Compress` is a `System.IO` stream.

```
System.IO.Stream s = new System.IO.Stream();
bmpObj.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, s);
```

What is the right way to do that, and with which stream?

Comment: Why not just Save : bitmap.Save(filename).  To write to a stream using MemoryStream instead of generic Stream.

Comment: @jdweng I'd love to do that, but don't know how.

Comment: Try following :             Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap("bit map");
            MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream();
            bitmap.Save(mStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            mStream.Position = 0;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Stream` is an abstract class - you need to use a concrete instance like `MemoryStream` or `FileStream`

```
using (System.IO.Stream outStream = System.IO.File.Create(targetFile))
{
  bmpObj.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, outStream);
}
```

Comment: Why not `using (System.IO.Stream outStream = new System.IO.Stream(file))`?

Also, I can't pass the targetFile in your example but I can pass it's path. Is it ok?

Comment: as I said, Stream is an abstract class.  You can't create an instance of an abstract class.  Check out a C# reference if you're unclear on abstract vs concrete classes.  In my example targetFile is a path to the file you want to create.